# Networking browsing crashes ESXi 5 Management interface

Tags: vmware-esxi

A couple of days ago we stumbled upon a disturbing issue with a relatively newly installed ESXi 5 management host for VDI. We were preparing a base VM for Linked-Clone deployment and when accessing its admin share from another machine ("\vm\c$") the entire Management network locks up. We can browse for a bit but after digging through a few folders Explorer hangs. The host and all other VMs inside of it are completely unreachable from the vSphere Client. If I physically walk over to the ESXi server I can login and reboot it and it will come back just fine. I can reliably crash it with any Windows-based VM (7 and 2008R2) 99% of the time. Today, I experimented with different physical ports on the server (there are 4) and found that once it crashes on a port, moving it to another and restarting the Management Network gets me back in, but if I fire up a share remotely I can crash that port, too. A reboot clears it all up.

I've combed through the logs on the server and haven't turned up anything of use. Any ideas?

Comment: what type of server is the host?

Comment: What has changed the day or two before this started happening?

Comment: @TheCleaner It's a Dell R720. The VMs we're working with are all on local storage.

Comment: @jftuga Unfortunately, nothing changed. We setup the server over a month ago and loaded up a few VMs to get started. It's been sitting in the rack mostly idle though.

Comment: Check the network switch ports for errors, collisions, retransmits, etc.

Comment: Hrmm... I would be taking a look at your host and physical switch and observing what MAC addresses are being used, making sure that the ESXi host, and each VM has a unique address

Comment: @jftuga Thanks for the suggestion. We watched the switch for errors and crashed the box twice without seeing any. Tried a new cable anyway and had the same results.

Comment: Could try disabling NetBIOS over TCP/IP for the intranet network adapter.

Comment: Are the VMs using the same subnet as the management network? If so, I suggest separating the two. Are you going from VM1 > VM2 on the same host or between 2 separate hosts?  I would also check out your vswitch and physical network setup on the host to make sure there aren't any weird loops.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all. I opened up a case with VMware and after about an hour with them we solved the issue. It's a bug with Broadcom's Ethernet driver. I'll post the details in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After about an hour with VMware support we got down to the bottom of the issue. There is a known bug with Broadcom's Ethernet driver and VMware. By disabling NetQ the problem has, so far, gone away. I still see a few second delay when browsing into certain folders over the network, but it eventually loads and doesn't crash the NIC.

```
~ # esxcfg-nics -l
Name    PCI           Driver      Link Speed     Duplex MAC Address       MTU    Description
vmnic0  0000:01:00.00 tg3         Up   1000Mbps  Full   24:b6:fd:f6:xxxx 1500   Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet
vmnic1  0000:01:00.01 tg3         Down 0Mbps     Half   24:b6:fd:f6:xxxx 1500   Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet
vmnic2  0000:02:00.00 tg3         Down 0Mbps     Half   24:b6:fd:f6:xxxx 1500   Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet
vmnic3  0000:02:00.01 tg3         Down 0Mbps     Half   24:b6:fd:f6:xxxx 1500   Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet
vmnic4  0000:42:00.00 ixgbe       Down 0Mbps     Half   90:e2:ba:0f:xxxx 1500   Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
vmnic5  0000:42:00.01 ixgbe       Down 0Mbps     Half   90:e2:ba:0f:xxxx 1500   Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
```

Count up the Broadcom/tg3 NICs (4 in our case).

```
~ # esxcfg-module -s force_netq=0,0,0,0 tg3
```

Reboot the host and you're done.

Comment: It's *always* a Broadcom issue...

Comment: @ewwhite We were slightly kicking ourselves for not going with the Intel card... there's a good chance we'll be swapping it out entirely now.